# Are my data a good candidate for EM imputation followed by exploratory factor analysis?

Tags: missing-data, factor-analysis, data-imputation, expectation-maximization, multiple-imputation

I am doing Exploratory Factor Analysis (EFA) in R, using principal axis factoring in the psych package. I have missing data that prevent me getting factor scores, so I am imputing data. I am using multiple imputation (PMM) in R by using the package ‘mifa’, calling the package ‘mice’, and then feeding the resulting correlation matrix to ‘psych’ for the EFA.

It would be much easier to use Expectation Maximisation, because later I would like to use the factor scores in further exploratory analysis and also for hypothesis testing. I did not do this because I understand EM to restrict standard errors and to be unsuitable for non-normally distributed data. However, reading further, I see that these problems are substantially mitigated when the proportion of missing data on each variable is relatively low, which is the case here. It ranges from 0-10.9%, with a mean of 3.4%. 5 variables have no missing data, 13 of the 61 variables have missing data above 5%, and the rest have some proportion in between. I now wonder, given the relative simplicity of using a single imputed dataset for operations on factor scores later on (for instance, latent profile analysis), would it be considered reasonable practice to use EM prior to the factor analysis?

Background: 221 participants indicated the extent of their agreement on 61 statements, using a 1-100 scale. Most (not all) variables have data that are skewed, some highly skewed, and some semi-continuous (high mass near 0 or 100). Missing data arise because participants sometimes select a ‘don’t know’ option. Around half of variables are eventually dropped due to low communalities (subject of a separate question [here.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/438833/should-items-with-low-intercorrelation-be-removed-before-efa-to-avoid-many-items))